# angular4 Routes not being kept on refresh

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript2.0, angular4-router

When reloading the page (F5 or typing the url into the address bar), the current route is not kept. I have a two separate modules, the main app module and then a dashboard module. These modules each have their own routing modules that they import. If I navigate to http://localhost it redirects to http://localhost/dashboard/overview but if I navigate to any other route though the address bar it redirects back to http://localhost/dashboard/overview

Clicking on any links on the pages that use routerlinks work fine.

I am using the latest angular 4 with the latest angular-cli. It worked before the update from angular 2 to angular 4.

Previous version of libraries:

```
"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
```

Current version of libraries:

```
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard/overview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {path: 'logs', component: LogsComponent},
  {path: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
  {path: 'metrics', component: MetricsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent},
      {path: 'partition/:type', component: DashboardPartitionComponent},
      {path: 'latency', component: DashboardLatencyComponent},
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

EDIT:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What HTTP server are you using and do you have it configured for HTML5 Pushstate support?

Comment: I am using Node.js with webpack. Everything is default as created by the angular-cli

Comment: Also note that this still happens when removing the default route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a call that would hijack the router and redirect to inject parameters. Before the update this.router.url would return the correct url. Now for some reason it always returns root.